# python dash app how to call it via a function within a python code

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Newbie to Dash.

I had a requirement to read a flat file and format it into CSV then create interactive graphs with preference to produce a flat file html format. So far I am just targeting this interactive app. If any suggestions to do the same that would be great.

If I try to call within the main python program the dash app vi  function it does not works, individually they work.
Question2: Why tool is asking again to Enter the path twice when I run the program?

Short snippet of Dash:

````
def Grapher(filepath):

    df = pd.read_csv(filepath+"\\"+'Output.txt',low_memory=False)

    app = Dash(__name__)

    x = '      Date/Time    '

    listA=\['Act. WPs','Dia.WPs'\\

    fig = px.scatter(df, x=x, y=listA\[0\],  title='Active Work Process Utilization' ,color='AS Instance        '   , height=700)
fig.update_layout( xaxis={'categoryorder': 'category ascending'} ,  xaxis_tickformat = '%d.%m.%Y       %H:%M:%S',xaxis_title="Application Server" ,legend_title_text="",legend=dict(
orientation="h"))

   fig2 = px.scatter(df, x=x, y=listA\[1\] ,  title='Active Dialog Work Process Utilization' ,color='AS Instance        '  ,height =700)

    fig2.update_layout( xaxis={'categoryorder': 'category ascending'}  ,xaxis_title="Application Server" ,legend_title_text="",legend=dict(orientation="h"))

```
 app.layout = html.Div(children=[
      # elements from the top of the page
      html.Div([
         html.H1(children='SDFMON Graphs Active Wps Dia'),
         #html.H4("SDFMON Graphs"),
         html.Div(children='''
         #Dash: First graph.'''),

         dcc.Graph(
            id='graph1',
            figure=fig
         ),
      ]),
      # New Div for all elements in the new 'row' of the page
      html.Div([
         html.H1(children='SDFMON Graphs Active Dialog Wps'),
         #html.H4("SDFMON Graphs"),
         html.Div(children='''
         #Dash: Second graph. '''),

         dcc.Graph(
            id='graph2',
            figure=fig2
         ),
      ]),
     ])

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.run_server(debug=True)
````

```
=====
MAIN PYTHON CODE:

    # Some line above this code to clean the file 

    location= input("Enter the name of the Path where output.txt exist")

   Grapher(location)

===============

Output :
Enter the name of the Path where output.txt exist C:\\Users\\PR_29-05-23 12-43-21
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

* Serving Flask app 'testing'
* Debug mode: on
  Enter the name of the Path where output.txt exist

Thank you !!!

When i remove the dash app out of function without asking for input and hardcoding the input then it works flawlessly.
```